# How to access custom data (added using a plugin) from orders array?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got the orders using wc_get_orders($order_id) and got the object. It looks like this:

```
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $order_id);
```

Data:

```
{  
   "id":1669,
   "parent_id":0,
   "status":"completed",
   "cart_hash":"8daaeb335972b31eb65f46bafb73bf39",
   "number":"1669",
   "meta_data":[  
      {  
         "id":4935,
         "key":"is_vat_exempt",
         "value":"no"
      },
      {  
         "id":4936,
         "key":"domain_name",
         "value":"mywebsite.com"
      },
      {  
         "id":4948,
         "key":"slide_template",
         "value":"default"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've removed unnecessary details. I want to get the "value" of "key:domain_name" under the meta_data array.

How can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta_data` don't have keys, so you need loop trough.

```
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $order_id);  
$domain = get_meta_item_value($customer_orders, 'domain_name');

function get_meta_item_value($ob, $key, $result = '') {
    foreach ($ob->meta_data as $meta_item) {
        if ($meta_item->key == $key) {
            $result = $meta_item->value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I did printf($meta_item) inside the foreach and it's not printing anything.

Comment: Working. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very nice answer.